# Synchronous require in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack and I'm using require to pull in some packages. I have two packages: package1.js and package2.js. package1.js simply creates an object with some properties called `pkg1`. package2 is a javascript file that contains a self executing function that extends package1. E.g.

package2.js:

```
!function () {
    pkg1.prototype.newFunction = function {return "foo"};
}()
```

I'm trying to require both of these into a new script in the following manner:

```
require('package1')
require('package2')
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: pkg1.newFunction is not a function
```

I think this is because of Javascripts asynchronous loading: `require(package2)` executes before `require('package1')`. My evidence for this is that when I do the following I don't get an error:

```
require('package1')
!function () {
    pkg1.prototype.newFunction = function {return "foo"};
}()
```

However, this is very messy, and I would like to use require. How would I go about making this work?

**Edit: Specific Examples**

The [leaflet-d3 plugin](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/leaflet-d3/blob/master/dist/leaflet-d3.js) begins with:

```
(function() {
    L.HexbinLayer = L.Class.extend({
    ...
 })()
```

Hence, at least to my understanding, putting in a `require(leaflet-d3-plugin)` should cause this script to execute and extend `L` which is brought in by `require('leaflet')`

Similarly, [d3-hexbin-v0](http://d3js.org/d3.hexbin.v0.min.js) starts with:

```
!function(){d3.hexbin=function(){
    ...
}}()
```

Again, the way I read this is that this script simply adds a `.hexbin` method to `d3`.

Now if I were just writing html, I would just put these different things in various script tags and this just works:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.hexbin.v0.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="static/leaflet-d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But since I'm using webpack, I should just be able to require and/or import these libraries after I have installed them with npm or if I just copy the .js in these scripts into some directory and then `require` them from that location. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work unless I copy the .js in these modules directly into whatever script I am writing. This is what I am trying to avoid.

E.g.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'; \\I'm using d3 v4 here.
require('/resources/d3-hexbin.min.js')
```

results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: d3.hexbin is not a function
```

Comment: *"package1.js simply creates an object with some properties called `pkg1`"* Ok. But where is the **variable** `pkg1` supposed to come from? *"I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: pkg1.newFunction is not a function`"* That usually happens when you are trying to **call** a value that is not a function. Where are you trying to call `pkg1.newFunction `? It seems your example is quite incomplete, which makes it hard to help you. Please read [mcve].

Comment: The `require()` calls are never actually executed in the browser. No browser supports require. Webpack builds a "bundled" javascript file with code set up to be browser compatible. further reading: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling for your feedback. I don't know how to make this verifiable without providing you with my entire webpack project, and I don't think anyone wants to go through that. I have expanded the question with some concrete examples. Hopefully they help in narrowing this down.

Comment: I wrote @asymmetrik/leaflet-d3. When I did, I messed up when I set up the module-based bundle for leaflet-d3 and it wasn't correctly specifying the dependencies on d3 and d3.hexbin, which caused problems when trying to use leaflet-d3 in a bundler like webpack. This meant you had to jump through hoops to get the d3.hexbin package registered correctly on the d3 global namespace and available to the right modues. The latest version (1.4) should correct this issue. You should only have to import d3 and d3-hexbin and configure d3 in your provide plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack loades it synchronously but each file have its own scope.

That's why in your statement

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'; \\I'm using d3 v4 here.
require('/resources/d3-hexbin.min.js')
```

your second doesn't find `d3` variable.

You can solve it by using `ProvidePlugin`:

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    d3: 'd3'
  }),
  ... //other plugins
```

This way `d3` will be available throughout the application.

Alternative way to achieve it is to use the following:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
window.d3 = d3;
require('./d3.hexbin.v0.min.js')
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: This is all good and correct info. The specific issue referenced in the question was related to a problem where d3-hexbin wasn't being loaded in the leaflet-d3 package scope. This cause the 'd3.hexbin is not a function' error. This specific problem is fixed in @asymmetrik/leaflet-d3 v1.4. Now, this answer should definitely work. All you'd need to do is import d3 and d3-hexbin and then configure the provide plugin.